# rails inverse of using 'references' in generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using model and migration generators in rails, you can use 'references' keyword as it was a data type to indicate that that field is a foreign key to another model, that is another table. 
In this example I do so with an author field inside a book table (actually the field won't be exactly 'author').

```
rails g model book title publication_date:date author:references
```

Looking at the migrations and models created, we can better understand what are the information that rails has guessed from the command (ok this is not a part of the question but more a summary of the logic and the state of the art of this command):

#### Migration

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :author, index: true
      t.date :publication_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here rails uses again the 'references' method as it was a data type, but it actually means that we are a layer on top on the 'basic' data structure level, infact referencing an author means, at the data level, to add an 'author_id' and not an 'author' column . And it does right so (i've also checked on schema.rb to have confirmation). 
In addition to this, it also puts an index: true that is a good practice from a performances point of view.

#### Model

Calling the generator in such a way also 'does something' on the model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

that is, it adds the 'belongs_to :author'. 
Notice that you can even create the book model and migration with the references clause to author *before* having author created. It enforces the consistence *at the end* (if it does at all, on such things).

#### Question

My question is on what rails doesn't do, that is: the has_many clause on the author model. 
1) since *normally* it does exist *before* having created the book model, it should be easy for rails to add has_many to this. Is there any parameter to say rails to do so? 
2) because of the fact that models can reference other models even if they are not yet created, another possibility would be declaring some kind of 'has_many' reference during author creation, is it possibile in some way?

Answer (score 1):

1. *There's no way of knowing where to put it*, you'd have to specify it.
   Such generators are designed to save time, and making such a thing saves too little or none. For instance, you'll have to specify explicitly the target class and whether it is `has_one` or `has_many`. That would subtract some of the usefulness of this, resulting in a very small positive or even a negative value.
2. I assume you mean that associations are available even on unsaved models. Yep, they are, but they're not too reliable. It works quite simple: an unsaved object has a collection for each association which stores temporary objects. When the main object is saved, new associated objects in these collections (not persisted yet) are created. An example:

   ```
   a = Author.new(name: "Charles Dickens")
   a.books << Book.new(title: "Oliver Twist")
   a.save
   ```

   That would save the new author to the database, and since his `id` would be known, it would then create a new book with that `author_id`. This behaves a little odd when it comes to `has_many ... through: ...` and possibly some other cases, so use this carefully.